# i'm trying to make a number guesser so when the button is pressed it should begin the game, the button works but the game will not begin

Tags: python, tkinter

it should make a windows and create a button which it does but when i click it it does not begin the game my code is:

```
from tkinter import *

a = False
import random
def start():
    a = True

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
btn = Button(window, text="Want to play a game?", bd = "5", command = start )
btn.pack(side = 'top')
window.mainloop()

if a == True:
    s = random.randint(1,4)
    t = int(input("Pick a number 1-4: "))
    if t != s:
        print("You lose!")
    else:
        print("You win!")
```

Comment: Do you know that code behind `window.mainloop()` will only be executed after `window` is closed?  Clicking the button does not close the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a global variable in a function except using the `global` keyword, because instead it will create a new local variable.

Also, the `if` statement will only run after the window is closed because the `mainloop()` function is running that whole time - instead just put all the code for the game in the `start()` function.

Code:

```py
import random

def start():
    s = str(random.randint(1,4))
    t = input("Pick a number 1-4: ")
    if t != s:
        print("You lose!")
    else:
        print("You win!")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
btn = Button(window, text="Want to play a game?", bd = "5", command = start )
btn.pack(side = 'top')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you it worked!